# How to pass arguments to Vue $createElement method

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, jsx

I'm trying to convert JSX code from example at http://element.eleme.io/#/en-US/component/tree#custom-node-content to Vue $createElement code

original code snippet:

```
renderContent(h, { node, data, store }) {
    return (
      <span>
        <span>
          <span>{node.label}</span>
        </span>
        <span style="float: right; margin-right: 20px">
          <el-button size="mini" on-click={ () => this.append(store, data) }>Append</el-button>
          <el-button size="mini" on-click={ () => this.remove(store, data) }>Delete</el-button>
        </span>
      </span>);
    }
}
```

and my attempt to transform:

```
  renderContent (h, { node, data, store }) {
    return h('SPAN', [
      h('SPAN', [h('SPAN', node.label)]),
      h('SPAN', {attrs: {style: 'float: right; margin-right: 20px'}}, [
        h('el-button', { attrs: { size: 'mini', on: { click: this.append(store, data) } } }, 'Append'),
        h('el-button', { attrs: { size: 'mini', on: { click: this.delete } } }, 'Delete')
      ])
    ])
  }
```

but it fails: the button `Append` always executed at the time of rendering for every node and never after. While button `Delete` is never executed at all.

So the question is how to pass an event handler with arguments properly to the created element?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's because you're actually calling the `append` function when rendering the content. Try this:

```
{ 
    attrs: { size: 'mini' }, 
    on: { click: this.append.bind(this, store, data) } 
}
```

or use the same solution as in the JSX snippet:

```
{ 
    attrs: { size: 'mini' },
    on: { click: () => this.append(store, data) } 
}
```

Both ways provide a function to be called when the click event occurs.

Notice that the `on` key is sibling to `attrs`, not inside.

Comment: first approach gives the error : Error in render function: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'bind' of undefined",
the second - no errors, but does nothing

Comment: That's strange... How it's then possible that `this.append(store, data)` in your code doesn't throw the error?

Comment: you are right I mistyped function name. So no errors and still event handler is not  being triggered. Then I checked documentation again and found out that put `on` key to a wrong place - inside `attrs` definition. After fixed - all works fine. Thank you so much!

Comment: @htonus right, I haven't notice the wrong placement of the `on` key. It's good that you figured it out. I'm updating my answer to reflect this aspect too.